# Why does Quick Select work 40 times slower if the partition function does not swap pivot with the last element?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I understand how quick select works, but my question is more about the partition function specifically than the general functionality of quick select.

Here's what a typical partition function would look like:

```
def _partition(start, end, pivot_idx):
    """
    Shuffle the array such that all numbers to the left of nums[pivot_idx] are smaller than it, and all numbers to the right are greater. Returns the new index of nums[pivot_idx].
    """
    pivot = nums[pivot_idx]
    nums[end], nums[pivot_idx] = nums[pivot_idx], nums[end]
    i = start # i stores the index of the last known number that's greater than pivot
    for j in range(start, end + 1):
        if nums[j] < pivot:
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
            i += 1
    nums[i], nums[end] = nums[end], nums[i]
    return i
```

The reason we swap `nums[end]` and `nums[i]` is because at the end of the algorithm, we want to place `pivot` at position `i`, and we can do that easily if we place `pivot` at the very `end` of the list.

However, that's not very intuitive to me. Nor is that very readable code. It would be (at least in my opinion) quite difficult for a programmer to understand who is not very familiar with quick select already.

So the question is how do we place `pivot` at position `i`? The very first idea that comes to mind is to simply update the `pivot_idx` variable correctly to point to `pivot` when we're playing around with the list in the `for` loop:

```
def _partition(start, end, pivot_idx):
    pivot = nums[pivot_idx]
    i = start # last known number greater than pivot
    for j in range(start, end + 1):
        if nums[j] < pivot:
            if i == pivot_idx:  # if we are swapping i and j but nums[i] is pivot, change pivot_idx to j.
                pivot_idx = j
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
            i += 1
    nums[i], nums[pivot_idx] = nums[pivot_idx], nums[i]
    return i
```

Using this, we can correctly place `pivot` (which is `nums[pivot_idx]` since `pivot_idx` always points correctly to `pivot`) without having to use weird tricks like remembering to swap the last element and the pivot.

However, I was surprised to find that this algorithm runs 40 times slower than the first one! I tested this on the online competitive coding website Leetcode: [Leetcode 215. Kth Largest Element in an Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-an-array/). The first algorithm takes on average, 60ms to complete all test cases, and the second one takes an average of 2400ms.

I can't begin to understand why there would be such a big slowdown. I am used to large differences in performance only when two algorithms differ in their Big O time complexities. What could be causing this behavior?

For reference, here is the complete code that calls `_partition` and returns the correct result (assume that it's never called with invalid inputs):

```
class Solution:
    def findKthLargest(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> int:
        def _partition(start, end, pivot_idx):
            """
            Shuffle the array such that all elements to the left of nums[pivot_idx] are lower than it and all the nums greater are to the right.
            """
            pivot = nums[pivot_idx]
            i = start # last known number greater than pivot
            for j in range(start, end + 1):
                if nums[j] < pivot:
                    if i == pivot_idx:
                        pivot_idx = j
                    nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
                    i += 1
            nums[i], nums[pivot_idx] = nums[pivot_idx], nums[i]
            return i

        start = 0
        end = len(nums) - 1
        idx = len(nums) - k
        while True:
            found_idx = _partition(start, end, idx)
            if found_idx == len(nums) - k:
                return nums[found_idx]
            elif found_idx < len(nums) - k:
                start = found_idx + 1
            else:
                end = found_idx - 1 
        return -1
```

Comment: A couple of notes. I don't really do Python (this is it, right?), but it seems to me you're including the `end` element in the compare loop in the first version - don't do that, it's where the pivot element is stored. As for the second version, once you've extracted the pivot _value_ into `pivot`, the pivot index is no longer relevant, or even valid, as you swap around elements, including the pivot value in the array. When you don't save off the pivot element at the end of the array, you don't actually need to do anything to get it (back) in the right place: it will just be at `i` in the end.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  Thanks for your comment! As for including the `end` element in the comparison: including it or not including it won't make a difference since the `<` comparison with itself will always fail, and the `if` condition will never be executed. As for your point about the second algorithm, you do need to put the pivot at the position `i` if you don't place it at the end. For example, if the input array is `[3,2,1,5,6,4]`, after the partition algorithm (where say, `pivot` is `4`), `i` will point to index `3`, but the algorithm won't work unless we place `4` at index `3`.

Comment: Both of the algorithms work correctly, it's just confounding to me as to why the second one would be so slow.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken a good look at the code, but I suspect not swapping pivot at the end of each partition step leads to worst case split of n-1, 1, and pivot, which results in O(n^2) time complexity, while for swapping pivot with pseudo random numbers will lead to a more ideal 70% | 30% split and O(n log(n)) time complexity.

You could test this by inserting print statements to show the lengths of each side of a partition after each split.

Comment: I'm not swapping the `pivot` with pseudo random numbers ever. Just that algorithm #1 swaps it at the end, and algorithm #2 doesn't swap it at all. Since the `pivot` (and the `pivot_idx`) in both of these algorithms is always the same, the resulting split after partition will always be the same too.

Comment: @a3y3 - I meant if the data that your sorting is pseudo-random, not a random pivot algorithm.